# Which product will give a better Wi-Fi reception?

Tags: usb, networking, wifi, network-adapter

My laptop's internal Wi-Fi antenna is horrible. At my school especially, it can only connect half the time, and when it does, rarely actually assigns me an IP address. I'm looking for a USB adapter that can help me actually get Wi-Fi at school (and anywhere else I might need it too). I'm wary of doing this, because I already have a USB Wi-Fi dongle ([Netgear wg111v3](http://firmware.netgear-forum.com/ntgfirm/img/produit/WG111v2h1_back_lowres.jpg)), but it's pretty much as bad as my internal one.

I have done some research, and narrowed it down to these two being best for my budget:

- [Hiro Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003516BJU)
- [Panda Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JDVRCI0)

So my question is: Which one will give me better reception and reliability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a pure numbers standpoint, the Hiro's 5dBi antenna beats the Panda's 2dBi antenna, and both beat the Netgear's tiny on-board antenna, so it's likely the Hiro will give you the best reception of the three.

You don't specify your budget, but it looks like about $20-ish.  If you're willing to go up to $30, the [Alfa AWUS036NH](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0035APGP6) has a powerful transmitter paired with a 5dBi antenna.  I've connected to access points with one from as much as half a mile away.  Assuming you're correct that your connection problems are due to low signal levels (and not high noise levels), it's a good choice.

Comment: hmm, i will check out the AWUS036NH. Have you gotten a chance to use it on Linux? A nice feature would be plug and play with linux
**EDIT**: Nevermind, it appears it does work with linux, but needs drivers

Comment: Works just fine on Linux, and every distro I've encountered has the drivers pre-installed.